# GLSL correct Gamma correction for premultiplied output

Tags: opengl, glsl

I am performing gamma correction of linear input in a fragment shader. But in my case the output pixel is also premultiplied (for the sake of correct alpha blending). I am not sure what is the correct order in this case:

```
 vec4 pixelOut = vec4(pow(color.xyz,vec3(1.0/2.2)) * alpha, alpha);
```

Or:

```
 vec4 pixelOut = vec4(pow(color.xyz * alpha,vec3(1.0/2.2)) , alpha);
```

Should I gamma correct the pixel color after it's premultiplied, or before?

Visually,I can't currently detect any difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

gamma correction should be the very last step in your shading pipeline. blending in sRGB space leads to incorrect results.
for a good explanation / discussion on this, have a look at Naty Hoffman's blog article [Adventures with Gamma-Correct Rendering](http://renderwonk.com/blog/index.php/archive/adventures-with-gamma-correct-rendering/).

> The correct thing to do is to perform blending like any other shading calculation – in linear space.

Therefore you should first premultiply with alpha and then take care of gamma correction.